# Syntax Error from VBA/SQL use of Like

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've got a sql command in vba (access 2007) that's giving me errors, and I don't know why. Specifically, it says that there's a missing operator in the WHERE clause. I can't figure out what is missing. It's not the UDF ReplaceNotAN, which replaces the specific non-alphanumeric characters.

Any ideas for what's going on, and how to fix it? Everything I could find for similar error on the intertubez is irrelevant (mostly about the single vs double quotes issue - but clearly that doesn't apply here).

```
dcSql = "UPDATE table SET table.Customer=ReplaceNotAN(Customer)" & _
    " WHERE table.Customer Like '*[-,.;:_'&=\/#]*';"
DoCmd.RunSQL dcSql
```

Comment: You have another ' in your string 'xxx'xxx'.

Comment: I am not sure why this was down voted. It is not that bad a question.

Comment: Me neither - these kinds of questions are immensely helpful, when I'm having issues like this, because they tell me other places to look. Voting it down means no one sees it, and then other people ask it, and... Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an additional single quote in the like phrase...

try it by doubling that one i think...

```
Like '*[-,.;:_''&=\/#]*';"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely it. Problem is, I kinda need that in there. I thought the brackets [] would prevent that from hitting. Is there another way to check for the presence of the '?

Comment: You have to escape it. Use two '' as in ...like 'abc''def'

Comment: Huzzah! That's it exactly. Thanks! I'll be marking this accepted in a little bit - won't let me check it yet.